# Error Al importar Go

Tags: go

al momento de importar un modulo de Go me presenta el siguiente error

> build command-line-arguments: cannot find module for path (el path donde tengo el archivo)

la estructura de mis archivos es la siguiente

```
main.go
jstructs/
    structs.go
```

y lo importo así:
import "./jstructs"

tengo mas módulos así y  no entiendo porque este me presenta error

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que estás utilizando [go modules](https://golang.org/ref/mod), lo que tienes que hacer es crear un módulo en el directorio principal `go mod init <module-path>`. El [module-path](https://golang.org/ref/mod#module-path) es un prefijo para los paquetes del mismo módulo así que puede darle el nombre que quieras. Finalmente, puedes importar cualquier paquete indicando previamente el módulo donde se encuentra, en tu caso sería `import <module-path>/jstructs`